# Electronのアプリケーションがnpm startできない

Tags: electron

先ほどElectronをインストールして、npm startしようとしたところ以下のようなエラーが吐き出されました。issuesを見てもあまりよく分からなかったのですが、何が原因なのでしょうか？
[image]

Comment: どのようにelectronをインストールしましたか?

Comment: npm init -y
npm install electron-prebuilt --save-dev
この順番でインストールを行いました。

Answer (score 1):

package.json の scripts に start コマンドを追加していないからです。

```
scripts {
  start: "electron ."
}
```

を追加するか、これが追加済みの https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start リポジトリを clone して始めると良いと思います。